# List files by last edited date

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory: `/home/user/`

How can I list every file in this directory (including those in sub directories) and order them by the date that they were last modified?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use:

```sh
ls -Rt
```

where `-R` means *recursive* (include subdirectories) and `-t` means "sort by last modification date".

---

To see a list of files sorted by date modified, use:

```sh
ls -l -Rt
```

An alias can also be created to achieve this:

```sh
alias lt='ls -lht'
lt
```

Where `-h` gives a more readable output.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

I added a -l in there too so I can actually see the dates so for anyone who searches this out later, it's-

$ ls -lRt

Comment: If you're doing this at the prompt and want to see the most recently modified files, consider `ls -lrt[RhA]`. the `-r` reverses the sort order, leaving recently edited stuff at the bottom of the list...

Comment: This added to a `-ila` gives you pretty much all the information you would need. `$ ls -ilaRt`

Comment: I have expanded on this answer because using `ll -Rt` was the perfect solution for me as I needed to see the files by date most recently modified.  This might be helpful to others.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy `ll` is does not exists and is not a command. It is mostly an alias in the bash shell, but not defined in most/some/? linux distributions. Some define it as an `alias ll='ls -l'` in /etc/bash.bashrc or /etc/.bashrc. Thus it may not work and it may not exists on OPs system. Use `ls -l -Rt` at least, as `ls` is a standard command as defined by posix. Or specify you meant `alias ll='ls -l'; ll -Rt`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay, I get that. I'll add that in because I think many people will find it useful.

Comment: @KamilCuk You can list whatever you like, but there is no need to be patronising.

Comment: This didn't do what I hoped.. it only sorts the files within each subdirectory, not globally.

Comment: This does not work on my Debian. Is does group directories and does only sort this after date, it does not sort every file according to the last modification date.

Answer (score 80):

If you'd like a master list in which all the files are **sorted together** by modification date, showing the directory they're in, but **not grouped by directory**, you can use this:

```
find . -type f -printf "%-.22T+ %M %n %-8u %-8g %8s %Tx %.8TX %p\n" | sort | cut -f 2- -d ' '
```

The result looks a lot like `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         3892 08/11/2009 11:03:36 /usr/share/man/man1/xmllint.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        22946 08/13/2009 11:59:20 /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root          728 08/17/2009 12:06:33 /usr/share/man/man1/thunderbird.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root          873 08/18/2009 10:52:47 /usr/share/man/man1/libgnutls-config.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         2552 08/19/2009 02:00:34 /usr/share/man/man3/Purple.3pm.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         9546 08/19/2009 02:02:00 /usr/share/man/man1/pidgin.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         2201 08/19/2009 02:02:46 /usr/share/man/man3/Pidgin.3pm.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root          926 08/19/2009 02:03:05 /usr/share/man/man1/purple-remote.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        18052 08/19/2009 04:11:47 /usr/share/man/man1/mono.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root         1845 08/19/2009 04:11:47 /usr/share/man/man5/mono-config.5.gz
```

---

## Mac OS X

For those of you using Mac OS X, option *-printf*  is not available on BSD find (you will get this error: `find: -printf: unknown primary or operator`). Fortunately you can Install GNU find through **Homebrew** (there should be an option to **Fink** and **Macports** as well):

```
brew install findutils
```

After install it the GNU find should be available to you as `gfind`. So, all you need to do is change the line above to:

```
gfind . -type f -printf "%-.22T+ %M %n %-8u %-8g %8s %Tx %.8TX %p\n" | sort | cut -f 2- -d ' '
```

Comment: Nice one.  The whole directory grouping thing with ls -R is annoying.

Comment: Great code, it took the script approx. 5 seconds to sort and print out 13k photos in many different folders (through Cygwin on a quite slow computer).

Comment: Oh now that is awesome. For people (like me) not as familiar with `find` as the author, those arguments to `-printf` are format directives that can be found in [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) (search for the fifth instance of `printf` in that page).

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this on MacOS but doesn't want to bother installing findutils: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%m %Sp %l %-8Su %-8Sg %8z %Sm %N" | sort | cut -f 2- -d' '` will give you roughly the same output on MacOS using only built-in utilities

Comment: `sort -r` to reverse the sorting and have the most recently modified files on top.

Answer (score 0):

**MAC OSX 2019**

If you don't care about what time it was created but you want your list sorted then  use this command

==> `ls -t`

If you want to order and see date and user info use this command

===> `ls -lt`

Answer (score 0):

For `zsh` users, you could also use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l141) (also documented on `man zshexpn`):

```sh
echo *(om)
```

Where `o` stands for *sort order, up* and `m` stands for *last modification time*.

This can be useful when used in a for loop or another command:

```sh
for file in *(^om); do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  # do something with file orderer from least recently modified to last modified
done
```

Or chained with another glob qualifier:

```sh
last_modified_file=(*(om[1]))
```