# How do I recursively list files within a directory in order of creation?

Tags: ruby, bash

I want to list all files, not directories, in the order of which they were created. I tried:

```
ls -R
```

which gets all the files, with some annoying formatting, that I would prefer line by line. However, my *nix-foo is pretty weak and I'm unsure how to order by created date.

Ultimately this will be done within a Ruby script, so if it's not possible with a magical bash command then some Ruby code is fine; I just thought it might be interesting and possibly cleaner to use bash.

Comment: ls -Rt  

see [bash-list-files-by-last-edited-date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404938/bash-list-files-by-last-edited-date

Comment: Almost, but I want order they were created, not edited date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Linux does not store the creation date. Mac OS does, but it isn't in a portable, readily readable format. Windows is the only system that does store it, but Ruby doesn't have any intrinsic commands that let you access it.

A careful reading of Ruby's `ctime`, which is often misread, shows it only supports the "change" time. Here are the docs for `ctime` from `File` and `File::Stat`:

> Returns the change time for file (that is, the time directory
>   information about the file was changed, not the file itself).

Comment: @qui, Here's a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5Dctime&submit=search) of Stack Overflow discussing the problem for Linux. Substitute the OS of choice in the resulting page's search box.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir['**/*'].reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }.sort_by { |f| File.ctime(f) }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, I usually use

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltrh
```

You can give ls all the formatting arguments you need.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Answer (score 0):

GNU find can help you, try this first

```
 find . -type f -printf "%C+\t%M\t%p\n" | sed 's/+/ /' | sort -t" " +0 -1
```

It may work.

But, I am using

```
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
```

And I couldn't get the `%C+` thingy to work.

So I came up with a long-hand printf format string that, as an added benefit, doesn't require the sed post-processing.

```
find .  -type f -printf '%CY-%Cm-%Cd.%CH%CM%CS\t%M\t%p\n'  | sort +0 -1n
```

Which gives output like

```
2011-03-30.141038.0000000000    -rw-r--r--      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-22011-03-30.140959.0000000000    -rwxr-xr-x      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7/doc/examples/.libs/reader3.exe
2011-03-30.141001.0000000000    -rwxr-xr-x      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7/doc/examples/.libs/reader3_ltshwrapper
2011-03-30.141001.0000000000    -rwxr-xr-x      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7/doc/examples/reader3.exe
2011-03-30.141002.0000000000    -rw-r--r--      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7/doc/examples/.deps/tree2.Po
2011-03-30.141002.0000000000    -rw-r--r--      ./pkgs/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7/doc/examples/tree2.o
```

The trailing `.0000000000` on each timestamp is fractional seconds, which apparently my system doesn't record. You can get HH:MM:SS formatting by using `%TX`.

If you need additional fields in your file listing (I threw in permissions as an extra), do `man find` and then search for `-printf`. There are a lot of arguments available for formatting the listing just about any way you need.

I note that you say 'want order they were created'. Unix has three time stamps that it stores for files, which does not include creation time,  so you can use display info as

```
%A  File's  last  access time
%C  File's  last  status change time
%T  File's last modification time
```

People often think that %C must mean create-time, but as you see abouve, it is 'status **change** time', which I think is last time any file permissions have changed. So for may cases that will be the file creation time, but it's not garanteed. (sp).

The manpage does not indicate that because Windows stores the creation time, that you can get it with `find`. Anyone?

I hope this helps.