# How to sort the files by date and saving that sorted ones (for convert append images)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert append images, but the images need to be sorted by date.

They are in my folder but not sorted.

How do I set it in order of modified date so I can use convert append in the way I want?

```
cd /home/campus/younggue.kim/Desktop/new/
```

I have many JPG files inside a folder named "kk", and I want to use the images in there.

```
 convert -append *.jpg output.jpg
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the names contain date information or must read from file creation timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files by last edited date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404938/608639), [How can I sort the output of 'ls' by last modified date?](https://superuser.com/q/147027/173513), [Sorting by date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8352/56041), etc. You have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change directory to `kk` and say:

```
convert -append $(ls -tr *.jpg) output.jpg
```

`ls -tr` sorts the files by modification time (oldest first, latest last) and the command substitution expands the sorted filenames as arguments for `convert`.