# Getting Last Modification Date of Files

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, command-line

I am writing a bash program to sort photos from different folders in order of their modification date. I know how to list all the names of the files, but how can I get their modification dates as well?

```
Matthews-MacBook-Air-3:Q3 Matthew$ find . -name '*.jpg'

./MontrealTest/daves_images/mtl10.jpg
./MontrealTest/daves_images/mtl7.jpg
./MontrealTest/gregs_photos/mtl1.jpg
./MontrealTest/photos_by_harth/mtl11.jpg
./MontrealTest/photos_by_harth/mtl5.jpg
./MontrealTest/photos_by_harth/mtl9.jpg
./MontrealTest/sandeeps_collection/mtl4.jpg
./MontrealTest/sandeeps_collection/mtl8.jpg
./MontrealTest.jpg
./SimpleTest/dir1/fee.jpg
./SimpleTest/dir2/fum.jpg
./SimpleTest/dir3/foo.jpg
./SimpleTest/dir4/foe.jpg
Matthews-MacBook-Air-3:Q3 Matthew$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files by last edited date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404938/list-files-by-last-edited-date)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of `find` you have (which generally depends on what OS you're using). If `find` supports the `-printf` primitive, you can do something like this (but see `man find` for more formatting options):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -printf '%t %p\n'
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-printf`, you can have it execute `stat` to do the same thing (and again, see `man stat` for more formatting options):

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec stat -f '%Sm %N' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

To get last modified date/time in human readable form of any file.

```
stat -c <format sequence> file
```

Where format sequence can be `%y` or `%z` or both if you want it in human readable form, or `%Y` or `%Z` or both if you want it in seconds since Epoch.

Examples:

```
stat -c %y new_file.txt
```

Sample output:

2018-09-22 17:32:02.264570176 -0700

```
stat-c %Y new_file.txt
```

Sample output:

1537662722

From `man stat`

> -c  --format=FORMAT
>          use the specified FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after each use of FORMAT
>
> %y     time of last data modification, human-readable
>
> %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
>
> %z     time of last status change, human-readable
>
> %Z     time of last status change, seconds since Epoch

I would say for accuracy, read the files in a variable when running find, then run stat, slower, but safer.